# How to get Racket in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, ppa

Is there a PPA or a package somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PPA for Racket now here:

https://launchpad.net/~plt/+archive/racket

Answer (score 1):

- It is in the repository as **plt-scheme**
- Install [**plt-scheme**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/plt-scheme) [image: Install plt-scheme]
- Also have a look at the **[Racket download page](http://racket-lang.org/download/)**.